# Laço While em PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x

Olá,
Eu estou fazendo um programa para guardar 'url' apenas para por em prática o quê já venho estudando em Python. Durante a elaboração do mesmo eu cheguei a uma trava e após dias estudando e lendo e tentando sair dela, não consegui resolver. Já li aqui no fórum para ver se achava alguma coisa que me ajudasse mas não consegui achar nada. Eu sou novato em programação e peço perdão se meu código não está de acordo com algum padrão de formatação.

A trava que cheguei foi que, se eu digitar uma opção diferente de 0, 1, 2 ou 9, o programa simplesmente para, não indo para o **else**, como eu esperava que fosse.

```
import sys  

print('--\tOpções\n'  
     '0\t-\tInserir \'url\' a lista.\n'  
     '1\t-\tVisualizar lista de \'url\'.\n'  
     '2\t-\tApagar \'url\' da lista (de acordo com a posição numérica).\n'  
     '9\t-\tSair do programa')  

escolha = 1000  
opcoes = int(input('Digite a opção desejada: '))

while opcoes == 0 or 1 or 2 or 9:

    if opcoes == 0 and escolha != 0:
        url = str(input('Digite a \'url\' destinada a armazenamento: '))
        arquivo = open('url.txt','a')
        arquivo.write(url + '\n')
        arquivo.close()
        escolha = int(input('\nDeseja armazenar outra \'url\'? SIM[\'1\'] / NÃO[\'0\']: '))
    if escolha == 0:
        escolha = int(input('\t0\t-\tFechar o programa\n'
                '\t1\t-\tMENU anterior: \n'
                'Deseja: '))
        if escolha == 0:
            print('\nAté logo!')
            sys.exit()
        elif escolha == 1:
            print('\n--\tOpções\n'
                '0\t-\tInserir \'url\' a lista.\n'
                '1\t-\tVisualizar lista de \'url\'.\n'
                '2\t-\tApagar \'url\' da lista (de acordo com a posição numérica).\n'
                '9\t-\tSair do programa')
            opcoes = int(input('Digite a opção desejada: '))

    if opcoes == 1 and escolha != 0:
        arquivo = open('url.txt', 'r')
        for linha in arquivo:
            print(linha.rstrip())
        arquivo.close()
        escolha = int(input('\nDeseja continuar usando o programa? SIM[\'1\'] / NÃO[\'0\']: '))
        if escolha == 0:
            print('Até logo')
            sys.exit()
        elif escolha == 1:
            print('\n--\tOpções\n'
                    '0\t-\tInserir \'url\' a lista.\n'
                    '1\t-\tVisualizar lista de \'url\'.\n'
                    '2\t-\tApagar \'url\' da lista (de acordo com a posição numérica).\n'
                    '9\t-\tSair do programa')
            opcoes = int(input('Digite a opção desejada: '))

    if opcoes == 2:
        print('Em construção')
        escolha = int(input('\nDeseja continuar usando o programa? SIM [\'1\'] / NÃO[\'0\']: '))
        if escolha == 0:
            print('Até logo')
            sys.exit()
        elif escolha == 1:
            print('\n--\tOpções\n'
                  '0\t-\tInserir \'url\' a lista.\n'
                  '1\t-\tVisualizar lista de \'url\'.\n'
                  '2\t-\tApagar \'url\' da lista (de acordo com a posição numérica).\n'
                  '9\t-\tSair do programa')
            opcoes = int(input('Digite a opção desejada: '))

    if opcoes == 9:
        print('\nAté logo!')
        sys.exit()

else:
    print('Você escolheu uma opção inválida')

print('Testando se está saindo do laço')
input()
```

Já leio aqui faz um tempo, mas sem conta registrada anteriormente, mas é a primeira pergunta que faço. Li os padrões que devem ser obedecidos para formatação de pergunta, mas peço perdão se deixei passar algum.

edit1: Eu pus um teste ao sair do laço **while** apenas para ver se estava saindo e não, não está saindo do laço. Como também não chega ao **else**. O programa apenas para.

Comment: coloquei mais informações na minha resposta - espero não ter deixado ainda mais confuso!

Comment: Não deixou! Foi muito clara. Obrigado por toda atenção e cuidado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O seu loop while:

```
while opcoes == 0 or 1 or 2 or 9:
```

Poderia ser escrito como:

```
while opcoes == 0 or True or True or True:
```

Se `opcoes` não for `0`, a expressão ficará:

```
while False or True:
```

que na tabela da verdade resultará em apenas `True` - ou seja, o seu loop é infinito.

> E não há problema nenhum, a princípio, em usar um loop infinito - mas me parece que você errou na indentação, e o último else está fora do loop:

```
#...
    if opcoes == 9:
        print('\nAté logo!')
        sys.exit()

# o else abaixo está fora da avaliação de 'opcoes'
else:
print('Você escolheu uma opção inválida')
```

> Mas se você colocar ele no loop, o seu `while` infinito fará ele lotar sua tela de "Você escolheu uma opção inválida".
>   Então você precisa, mais uma vez, pedir o input do usuário:

```
else:
print('Você escolheu uma opção inválida')
opcoes = int(input('Digite a opção desejada: '))
```

---

Dito tudo isso, eu sugiro que você reescreva seu código. Toda vez que você perceber que seu código está repetitivo, e que você anda copiando e colando partes prontas como o menu, no seu caso, tem alguma coisa errada.

Uma maneira "lógica" de se fazer isso seria criar um `while` que só se preocupa com o comando de "sair" - e seria interessante também você tentar remover todas as cópias de menus que você fez, e pedir o input do usuário dentro desse loop `while` - eu começaria de novo assim:

```
opcoes = 0
while opcoes != 9:
  print('--\tOpções\n'  
    '0\t-\tInserir \'url\' a lista.\n'  
    '1\t-\tVisualizar lista de \'url\'.\n'  
    '2\t-\tApagar \'url\' da lista (de acordo com a posição numérica).\n'  
    '9\t-\tSair do programa')  

  opcoes = int(input('Digite a opção desejada: '))
  if opcoes == 0:
    print("Testando opção 0")
  if opcoes == 1:
    print("Testando opção 1")
  if opcoes == 2:
    print('Em construção')
  if opcoes == 9:
    print('\nAté logo!')
```

#### Edit

Para explicar melhor o caso do while:

```
while opcoes == 0 or 1 or 2 or 9:
```

`opcoes == 0` é uma expressão que pode ser avaliada em `True` ou `False` - enquanto `opcoes == 0` for `True`, o laço executa.

Mas o seu `while` tem outras "expressões", entre cada um dos `or`.

`1` é uma expressão, que em Python é avaliada em `True`.
`2` também é uma expressão que em Python é avaliada em `True`.

Por isso a solução da outra resposta funciona - ele troca a "expressão" `1` por `opcoes == 1` - ele dá à expressão, a possibilidade de ser avaliada em `False`, e o loop deixa de ser infinito.

Supondo que `opcoes` não seja igual a 0, `opcoes == 0` seria falso. E com `1` sendo avaliada para `True`, você acaba com o seguinte `while`:

```
while False or True:
```

E se você verificar a tabela da verdade para `OR`, vai ver que o resultado é `True` e portanto o loop roda infinitamente.

Answer (score 3):

Faz assim amigo, tenho certeza que vai funcionar, no loop while coloca:

```
while opcoes == 0  or opcoes == 1 or opcoes == 2 or opcoes == 9:
```

Comment: Obrigado! Resolveu meu problema. Me surgiu outra dúvida com sua resposta, mas por erro meu mesmo. Antes estava dando certo se eu não trouxesse o erro pro programa. Eu quero dizer o seguinte: se eu digitasse dentro do previsto pelo programa, ele ''ativava'' o laço **while**. Era apenas se eu saísse do previsto que acontecia o que eu descrevi acima. Fazendo da forma que você me instruiu dá certo, mas porquê antes dava meio certo e meio errado? Você sabe dizer?

Comment: Desculpa cara, não sei te responder, se desse algum erro na execução do script daria pra saber, só que não dá, mas agora vc ja sabe como resolver, e vai passar a fazer a msm coisa nos proximos codigos que  vai construir!

Comment: Muito obrigado de toda forma! Eu irei ficar fazendo testes aqui para ver se consigo 'me' responder.
Novamente, obrigado pela atenção!